# ImproperlyConfigured Circular Import error Django2 Python3

Tags: django, python-3.x

## I continue to get this error even after updating syntax to django2/python3 compatible. No mis-naming that I can see after checking repeatedly.

I have tried using url instead of path and django 1 but this still does not fix the issue

hackuta/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.HomePage.as_view(),name='home'),
    path('first_app/',include('first_app.urls'),namespace = 'first_app'),
    path('first_app/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('test/',views.TestPage.as_view(),name='test'),
    path('thanks/',views.ThanksPage.as_view(), name='thanks')
]
```

Error displayed when trying to migrate:

```
File "/home/bbwslayer/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 593, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'hackuta.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

How do I fix this issue for a smooth migration?

EDIT:
I followed the advice of one of the comments and it turns out when I comment out the following line I can migrate just fine:

```
    path('first_app/',include('first_app.urls'),namespace = 'first_app'),
```

I felt it would be fitting to include the code for first_app.urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'first_app'
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name = 'first_app/login.html'),name = 'login'),
    path('logout/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(),name='logout'),
    path('signup/',auth_views.SignUp.as_view(),name='signup')
]
```

Comment: The error msg not helping? "URLconf 'hackuta.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import."

Comment: I found the easiest way to find the offending path is to comment each line one at a time until the error is no longer popping up.

Comment: Was leaving off the closing bracket a typo?

Comment: I assume it was since it would throw a `SyntaxError`, so I went ahead and added it to your question.

Comment: @JoshuaPierce Followed your advice and edited the post to include the line that was giving me the issue, also included the first_app.urls code

Comment: So your root project folder (ie `hackuta/hackuta`) has a `views.py` right?

Comment: @CalebGoodman yes it looks like this:
```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView



class TestPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'test.html'
class ThanksPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'thanks.html'
class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

Comment: Can you edit the question with your file structure?

Comment: I am trying to recreate your issue, and I ran into a few errors: `namespace` is no longer a supported keyword, use `name` instead, also `django.contrib.auth.views` doesn't have a `SignUpView`

Comment: Other than that I'm out of ideas.  Can you link to a github project for this?  It would be much easier to debug then.

Comment: @CalebGoodman here is an image of the file structure:
https://imgur.com/a/FiYlbti
Also I would upload to github but my team doesn't want me to, apologies for this and if i'm being difficult this is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that every `urls.py` has **urlpatterns** in it, like this:

```
urlpatterns = []
```

Also, make sure that you added the closing bracket to `urlpatterns` in `hackuta/urls.py`, because you left it off in your question!

Comment: I do have the end bracket for the urlpatterns list shown, are you referring to another list?

Comment: @ArjunPatel you made a typo in your question, and I edited it in (so don't worry about it).  Can you update your question with the `urls.py` for `first_app`?  Also, is `hackuta` the name of your project?  or is that an app?

Comment: the name of the project is hackuta, first_app is the name of the application I created, I included the code for first_app.urls as i'm still unsure what is giving me the issue

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
path('first_app/', include('first_app.urls', namespace='first_app')),
```

Instead of:

```
path('first_app/', include('first_app.urls'), namespace='first_app'),
```

---

`namespace` is an argument to [include](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fa8fe09e4e2b538c5d50a559081861d5c0635d55/django/urls/conf.py#L12) and not [path](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fa8fe09e4e2b538c5d50a559081861d5c0635d55/django/urls/conf.py#L76).